# Regarding changing from Lebesgue to Riemann integral in proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Given $f:[0,\infty] \rightarrow [0,\infty]$, measurable and decreasing, show that $f\in L^1 \iff \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k) < \infty$. I have the following:

For $\implies$, we can show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^m f(k) \leq \int_0^m f(x)$$
So, by the Monotone Convergence theorem
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^m f(k) \leq \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{[0,m]}f(x) = \int_0^\infty  \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{1}_{[0,m]}f(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x) < \infty$$

However im not using the lebesgue integral, im just assuming I can use the Riemann integral (from what I see), is this the correct way to proceed?

Comment: What part is specific to the Riemann integral?

Comment: @Lorago For example, for the first inequality, can we say the same for a Lebsegue integral? i.e. $\sum_{k=0}^m f(k) \leq \int_0^m f(x)\,\lambda(dx)$?

Comment: Indeed, and it shouldn't be hard to prove with the given properties of $f$. You can also see that it's true as since $f$ is decreasing, its continuous a.e., and hence Riemann integrable, and so as $[0,m]$ is a compact interval, this Riemann integral equals the corresponding Lebesgue integral, but that's a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were unsure about how to show the inequality you used for the Lebesgue integral, notice that

$$\sum_{j=1}^nf(j-1)=\sum_{j=1}^n\int_{j-1}^jf(j-1)~\mathrm{d}\lambda\geq\sum_{j=1}^n\int_{j-1}^jf~\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int_0^nf~\mathrm{d}\lambda=\sum_{j=1}^n\int_{j-1}^jf~\mathrm{d}\lambda\geq\sum_{j=1}^n\int_{j-1}^jf(j)~\mathrm{d}\lambda=\sum_{j=1}^nf(j),$$

since $f$ is decreasing. In particular we get the inequalities

$$\sum_{j=1}^nf(j-1)\geq\int_0^nf~\mathrm{d}\lambda\geq\sum_{j=1}^nf(j),$$

from which you get the result by just taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ and applying the Monotone Convergence theorem.

Comment: Shouldn't the sums be switched at the last inequality?

Comment: @Hlkwtz ah yes, that was a typo, thanks